# ¿Cómo puedo instalar la libreria tensoflow en Python 3.7?

Tags: python, tensorflow, python-3.7

He seguido todas las instrucciones para instalar la librería desde la web oficial, pero no lo consigo.

El error que me sale en consola es:

`Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tensorflow`

y mi versión es:

`Python 3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:59:51)`.

No entiendo qué ocurre.

Comment: La compatibilidad con Python 3.7 no está lista aún.

Comment: Y que librería me recomiendas para programar neuronas?

Comment: CatBoost puede ser una alternativa muy buena. [Link](https://github.com/catboost/catboost)

Comment: Gracias por la contestación, aun así he hecho lo siguiente y si no te importa asesorarme. He instalado el modulo sklearn, y me da fallos diferentes en dos IDE's. Sublime Text me da el siguiente error con el modulo sklearn.neural_network: ` DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib; see the module's documentation for alternative uses` y con el PyCharm el clásico error de `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn'`. ¿Puede ser que tengas diferentes versiones de Python en las IDE's? ¿Debo crearme un ambiente con Anaconda para poder utilizar uno u otro?
Gracias.